# Removing Apache Vhost

Tags: apache, laravel, vhosts

I'm in a new pc, and the previous intern has configured a virtual host(vhost) on Apache. I'm trying to remove, because i don't accessing any project on folder "www"(wampo).It always redirected to folder "bignardi"(laravel).

I remove the lines from httpd-vhosts.conf and hosts(drivers/etc - windows).

Answer (score 0):

In Wamp folder i found a folder named "vhosts" and i removed the lines to create the virtual host.